# I can't connect to localhost (Openserver , JDBC , MySQL)

Tags: java, android, mysql

I try connect

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logins_db","root","")
```

but it's doesn't work

I use openserver, phpMyAdmin and use Nox emulator.

1. I tried to connect using the ip address of the android
   (172.17.100.2/openserver/logins_db/) because I run through the
   emulator
2. I tried to connect using the ip address of the android
   (localhost/openserver/logins_db/) because I run through the emulator

Yes, I enabled internet permission

```
 TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tv_connect_text);
        String text="";
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                text += "We don't find your driver!";

                e.printStackTrace();
                text+=e.toString();
            }

            Connection connection = null;

            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logins_db","root","");
            }
            catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                text += "Connection failed!\n";
                text +=e.toString()+"\n";
            }

            if(connection!=null){
                text += "You are connect! Congratulate";
            }

            textView.setText(text);
```

result:

> Connction failed!
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLnonTranseitConnectionException:
>   Could not create connection to database server.]

I know that there was a similar question, but I'm wondering why the application can not find the database?

Comment: Did you use the emulator to connect localhost? Use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead.

Comment: Of course. I wrote that ip adress 172.17.100.2 for Nox emulator (I use it). Ip 10.0.2.2 doesn't work for my em.